# Duplicated Rows in Mixed Data Type Clustering

Tags: clustering, large-data, weighted-data, mixed-type-data, k-medoids

I have a dataset which has ~200k rows and looks like the following -

`id - ids which are unique
col1 - categorical with 3 levels
col2 - categorical with 5 levels
col3 - numerical 
col4 - categorical with 5 levels`

However, the number of unique rows in this dataset once the id column is removed is only ~1000 rows.

I am trying to use PARTITIONING AROUND MEDOIDS (PAM) clustering in R which requires Gower distance matrix to be calculated. 
However, calculating this matrix is intensive and the final result will not fit in memory.

I looked at adding weights to each of these duplicated rows when using Gower distance but it looks like from this question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334677/how-do-i-weight-variables-with-gower-distance-in-r, that weights can be set for columns but not rows.

I also looked at [Do I need to remove duplicate objects for cluster analysis of objects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152808/do-i-need-to-remove-duplicate-objects-for-cluster-analysis-of-objects) but I am not able to find a solution/best practice.

Any suggestions on how duplicate rows are handled in clustering?

Comment: In methods like k medoids or k means duplicated objects clearly affect results. If weighting option is not or cannot be implemented then you are left with the usual problem of too-big-matrix-to-analyze. Try to do your clustering on a random subset(s) of your 200k object dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Get the source code.

The `cluster` package is **open source**, so you can modify it and add support for weighting. I am convinced the authors will be happy to receive such an extension and make it available for future users!

But before, you may want to first check that you are on the right track:

1. Try a sample. Use 10k rows, and check if the clusters work for you.
2. Try unweighted. Maybe the duplicates don't need to be considered, and the result is good enough without (or even better?)